# Quais as principais diferenças entre .html(), .replaceWith() e .text() em jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Eu tenho o seguinte elemento `HTML`:

```
<text class='car'>
  Oi, este é meu carro amarelo: <i class='fa fa-car' style='color:yellow;background-color:green;'></i>
</text>
```

E eu quero manipular o *conteúdo* dele através de *`jQuery`*.

Primeiro, usei `.html()`:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('.car').html('<text class="car">Oi, este é meu carro vermelho: <i class="fa fa-car" style="color:red;background-color:green;"></i></text>');
  });

</script>
```

E depois `.replaceWith()`:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('.car').replaceWith('<text class="car">Oi, este é meu carro vermelho: <i class="fa fa-car" style="color:red;background-color:green;"></i></text>');
  });

</script>
```

E não teve diferença (não a olho nú, pelo menos).

Já o método `.text()` não aceita a marcação `HTML` (ex. `<div>Oi</div>`), apenas modifica o conteúdo *textual* do elemento. Assim, não tem como colocar o ícone e não sei se o elemento é eliminado ficando apenas a *string*.

Então:

- Quais as principais diferenças entre `.html()`, `.replaceWith()` e `.text()` e quando será preferível usar uma a outra?

**Ícones e *jQuery***

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Exemplificando com o seu Código.**

**DOM :**

```
<text class='car'>
    Oi, este é meu carro amarelo: <i class='fa fa-car' style='color:yellow;background-color:green;'></i>
  </text>
```

**HTML JQUERY :**

```
$('.car').html('NOVO HTML');
```

**RESULTADO :**

```
<text class="car">NOVO HTML</text>
```

---

**REPLACEWITH JQUERY :**

```
$('.car').replaceWith('NOVO HTML');
```

**RESULTADO :**

```
'NOVO HTML'
```

### EXPLICANDO

- **.html**

O método [html()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_html.asp) define ou retorna o conteúdo (innerHTML) dos elementos selecionados. Quando este método é usado para retornar conteúdo, ele retorna o conteúdo do **PRIMEIRO** elemento correspondente. Quando este método é usado para definir o conteúdo, ele substitui o conteúdo de **TODOS** os elementos correspondentes.

---

- **.replaceWith**

O método [replaceWith()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_replacewith.asp) substitui os elementos selecionados por um novo conteúdo, Coloquei alguns recursos do replaceWith no Código.

---

- **.text**

O método [text()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_text.asp) define ou retorna o conteúdo de texto dos elementos selecionados.

Quando esse método é usado para retornar conteúdo, ele retorna o conteúdo de texto de todos os elementos correspondentes (a marcação HTML será removida).

Quando este método é usado para definir o conteúdo, ele substitui o conteúdo de **TODOS** os elementos correspondentes.

**CONCLUSÃO**

**- HTML**

1 - pode ser usado para obter o conteúdo de qualquer elemento.

2 - remove outras construções, como manipuladores de dados e eventos de elementos filhos antes de substituir esses elementos pelo novo conteúdo.

3 - Para definir o conteúdo de um  elemento, que não contém HTML, use o .text()método e não .html().

4 - Utilização de Função

```js
$( ".elemento1" ).html(function() {
  var emphasis = "<em>" + $( "p" ).length + " paragraphs!</em>";
  return "<p>All new content for " + emphasis + "</p>";
});
```

---

**- REPLACE**

1 -  Remove o conteúdo do DOM e insere novo conteúdo em seu lugar com uma única chamada.

2 -  Método remove todos os manipuladores de dados e eventos associados ao Elemento Removido.

3 -  Um elemento também pode ser selecionado como substituto, Exemplo : $( ".elemento1" ).replaceWith( $( ".elemento2" ) );

4 - O replaceWith() na verdade não excluirá o elemento, mas simplesmente o removerá do DOM e o retornará para você na coleção.

---

**- TEXT**

1 - A Baixo nivel o text(), Chama o método DOM .createTextNode(), ***que não interpreta a string como HTML***.

2 - Pode ser usado em documentos XML e HTml.

3 - método nos permite definir o conteúdo do texto passando uma função.

```js
$( ".elemento1" ).text(function( index ) {
  return "item number " + ( index + 1 );
});
```